# How to improve this csv dataframe comparator code?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, compare

I'm trying to generate a csv. that stores the percentage of error between two .csv. The . csv' have the same number of columns and rows, but are calculated by different providers. I want to check the variation (percentage) between each cell, and store it as a . csv. 
The following script is currently working, but it takes too long:

```
import pandas as pd

try_1 = pd.read_csv('try.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
test_1 = pd.read_csv('test.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
try_1_df = pd.DataFrame(try_1)
test_1_df = pd.DataFrame(test_1)

results = try_1_df.copy()
percentage = try_1_df.copy()

for col in try_1_df.columns:
    for i in range(try_1_df.shape[0]):
        if i > 0 and col != 'date':
            try:
                results.loc[i, col] = float(try_1_df.loc[i, col])-float(try_1_df.loc[i, col])
                if float(try_1_df.loc[i, col]) != 0:
                    percentage.loc[i, col] = (float(results.loc[i, col]) / float(try_1_df.loc[i, col])) * 100
                else: percentage.loc[i, col] = 'ok'
            except KeyError:
                print(col)

percentage.to_csv('percentage_test.csv')
```

I think it can be done much easier, does anyone have any idea how to simplify it?

The .csv' look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can just do a `sub` and `div`:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 3)).floordiv(.1)
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 3)).floordiv(.1)
>>> df1
     0    1    2
0  2.0  6.0  6.0
1  0.0  9.0  6.0
2  0.0  9.0  0.0
3  3.0  8.0  2.0
4  2.0  2.0  5.0
>>> df2
     0    1    2
0  2.0  3.0  4.0
1  8.0  8.0  8.0
2  3.0  9.0  1.0
3  9.0  8.0  3.0
4  1.0  3.0  4.0
>>> diff = df1.sub(df2)
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.where(diff.ne(0), df1.div(df2).mul(100), 'ok'))
                   0                  1                  2
0                 ok              200.0              150.0
1                0.0              112.5               75.0
2                0.0                 ok                0.0
3  33.33333333333333                 ok  66.66666666666666
4              200.0  66.66666666666666              125.0
```

And if you need to ignore the first row, just do `diff = df1.loc[1:].sub(df2.loc[1:])`

Answer (score 2):

df_a

```
             client1   client2   client3   client4
date                                              
2020-02-26  0.880479  0.635249  0.862602  0.946269
2021-02-26  0.652312  0.481930  0.875188  0.497397
2022-02-26  0.920294  0.843312  0.986989  0.030338
2023-02-26  0.189162  0.881262  0.610923  0.289938
```

df_b

```
             client1   client2   client3   client4
date                                              
2020-02-26  0.912638  0.622160  0.306025  0.177105
2021-02-26  0.557815  0.007662  0.249375  0.382226
2022-02-26  0.359068  0.286853  0.949497  0.099637
2023-02-26  0.592457  0.215549  0.351929  0.356738
```

Absolute percent difference between each corresponding cells

```
df = abs(df_a.divide(df_b) - 1)
```

df

```
             client1    client2   client3   client4
date                                               
2020-02-26  0.035237   0.021038  1.818733  4.342989
2021-02-26  0.169407  61.899576  2.509519  0.301318
2022-02-26  1.563008   1.939873  0.039487  0.695515
2023-02-26  0.680716   3.088451  0.735926  0.187252
```

IMO variance or standard deviation between clients or entire data sets even may be a better representation of 'variation' between data providers.